# C function not working

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming, and I was trying a function to swap the variables of an array, but I just cannot get it to work, and I don't know why. Can you please help me? Thank you in advance.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void inplace_swap(int *x, int *y){
    if (x!=y){
        *y = *x ^ *y; 
        *x = *x ^ *y; 
        *y = *x ^ *y; 
    }
}

void reverse_array(int a[], int cnt){
    int first, last;
    for (first = 0, last = cnt-1; first <= last; first++, last--)
        inplace_swap(&a[first], &a[last]);
}

int main(){
    //int eight = 80, seven = 70;
    //inplace_swap(&eight, &seven);
    //printf("New eight value is %d\n", eight);
    //printf("New seven value is %d\n", seven); 

    int arr[5] = {1,2,3};
    reverse_array(&arr[3], 2);
    printf("%d\n", arr[1]);
    //int i;
    //for (i=0;i < 4;i++) {
    //  printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    //}
}
```

Comment: What results are you getting? What have you tried and have you used a debugger?

Comment: `reverse_array(&arr[3], 2);` why are you passing address of element that you did not explicitly initialise?

Comment: Aside from the problems above, you're only printing the second element of `arr`, `printf("%d\n", arr[1]);` -> `for ( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i ) printf("%d\n", arr[i]);`

Comment: The `XOR` swap is so 1980's. Use a temporary variable, then the algorithm will work with floating point types too.

Comment: If you're reversing only the elements of indices 3 and 4 (which haven't been initialised), then displaying the element at index 1, what exactly are you expecting it to display?

Comment: @WeatherVane sorry, misread it. Forget the comment. I'll delete it, as well as this comment.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I have made plenty of those myself ;)

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I already solved it. The mistake was with the array call. :)

Answer (score 2):

The `reverse_array` function works fine, but you don't call it correctly in main:

You want this:

```
int main() {
  int arr[] = { 1,2,3 };
  reverse_array(arr, 3);

  int i;
  for (i=0;i < 3;i++) {
    printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
  }
}
```

There are 3 problems in your code:

```
// here you declare an array of size 5 but you only initialize the first 3 elements
//This is not actually a problem in first place
int arr[5] = {1,2,3};     

// &arr[3] is the address of 4th element of the array, which has not
// been initialized, This actually swaps arr[3] with arr[4]
reverse_array(&arr[3], 2);

// here you print the second element which has not been modified
// at all by the reverse_array(&arr[3], 2);
printf("%d\n", arr[1]);
```

As already mentioned, the XOR swap stuff is old fashioned and works only for integral types.

Comment: Thank you very much, the mistake was with calling the array. I fixed it and it works correctly!

Answer (score 1):

From your code seems that you want to swap the last two elements from your array that are 0,0
Your array of 5 element is initialized with 1,2, 3, 0,0
When you call swap function with the address of 'third' element which is actually the fourth element of array you basically swap the 4th and 5th element of array and you actually print the 2nd element of array

Comment: This is a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

This code works well:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void inplace_swap(int *x, int *y){
   if( x != y ) {
      *y = *x ^ *y;
      *x = *x ^ *y;
      *y = *x ^ *y;
   }
}

static void print_array( int arr[], size_t count ) {
   size_t i;
   for( i = 0; i < count; ++i ) {
      printf( "%s%d", i ? ", " : "", arr[i] );
   }
   printf( "\n" );
}

static void reverse_array( int a[], int cnt ) {
   int first, last;
   for( first = 0, last = cnt-1; first <= last; first++, last-- ) {
      inplace_swap(&a[first], &a[last]);
   }
}

int main() {
   int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
   size_t count = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
   print_array  ( arr, count );
   reverse_array( arr, count );
   print_array  ( arr, count );
}
```

Execution trace:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

All the comments and answers need to be understood so you learn what mistakes you made. With that being said, I re-worked your code just a bit to make it work. Please study the differences and ask questions...

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*** Prototypes - get in the habit of using them ***/
void inplace_swap(int *x, int *y);
void reverse_array(int *a, int cnt);
/***************************************************/

#define NUM_ELEMENTS(x)     (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))    

void inplace_swap(int *x, int *y)
{
    if (*x!=*y)
    {
        printf("Doing swap...\n");
        *y = *x ^ *y; 
        *x = *x ^ *y; 
        *y = *x ^ *y; 
    }
}

void reverse_array(int *a, int cnt)
{
    int first, last;

    for (first = 0, last = cnt-1; first <= last; first++, last--)
    {
        inplace_swap(&a[first], &a[last]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,1,2};

    reverse_array(arr, NUM_ELEMENTS(arr));

    for ( int i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS(arr); ++i )
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Assuming that the `XOR` swap must be used (it is horrible), instead of `if (x != y)` the condition `if (*x != *y)` would also cover the condition where the data is the same, as well as the pointers being the same.

Comment: I will have a look at it, thank you! Your help was great guys!

Comment: @DIEGOBERNALADELANTADO Yes, it's a neat little 'trick' that some coders use.

Comment: This is a way of defining a function? #define NUM_ELEMENTS(x)     (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))

Comment: @DIEGOBERNALADELANTADO It's called a macro.

Comment: @DIEGOBERNALADELANTADO If you found some good information in my answer, it would be nice of you to upvote it. :-)

Comment: @Chimera yes, sorry, I'm new to this. :O